# Datagrid view text boxes losing value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Data grid view in which I have changed all the cells to text boxes to allow for a bulk update. The problem is that the users new input values are not registering and instead the cells are holding the old values. I taught it might be to do with a post back issue but cant imagine it is as there is no loading of old data in the page load. I also considered that the text boxes might not be registering properly because they are added without an ID but not to sure on that.

Changed cells to textboxes here.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 4; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        TextBox test = new TextBox();
        test.Text = row.Cells[i].Text.ToString();
        row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(test);
    }
}
```

trying to pull new values and them to list newValues here

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) {
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        bool isChecked = row.Cells[0].Controls.OfType < CheckBox > ().FirstOrDefault().Checked;
        if (isChecked) {
            string table = DropDownList1.Text.ToString();
            List < string > selectedValues = CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast < ListItem > ()
                .Where(li = > li.Selected)
                .Select(li = > li.Value)
                .ToList();

            List < string > newValues = new List < string > ();

            int userid = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Text.ToString());
            //GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            Label lblID = (Label) row.FindControl("WDB_Id");
            //TextBox txtname=(TextBox)gr.cell[].control[];
            for (int i = 4; i < selectedValues.Count + 4; i++) {
                newValues.Add(row.Cells[i].Text.ToString());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is that code to change to textbox is? I guess it has to be in the preinit and you need to check for IsPostBack so you don't overwrite it.

Comment: You have to provide name of the control and during postback event you have to retrieve value with Request.Form[""] property.  These control created dynamically so ViewState doesn't know how to bind the new value to it.